# Uploading files to express

Tags: express, file-upload, multer

I want to upload files from a ReactJS app to an ExpressJS server.

My request is looking as follows:

[image: Request headers]

[image: Request body]

As you can see, the Content-Type header is set correctly, to allow files to be uploaded.

Now, in ExpressJS I have the following code in `index.js`:

```js
    const express = require('express');
    const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

    const app = express();

    app.use(fileUpload({
        createParentPath: true
    }));
    app.use(express.json());
```

My output from a `console.log(req.body)` is as follows:
[image: Output]

I get the same result when using `multer`. `body-parser` is deprecated, but using `express.urlencoded({extended: true})` also gives the same result.

My expected output is just an object with the body and I expect `req.files` to contain the image. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: The request looks good. Could you post the code in the route in your backend where you're console.logging the file/body?

Comment: ```const addMenuItem = async (req, res, next) => {
    data = req.body;
    console.log(data);
}````